# is data encrypted during request to azure key vault using GetSecretAync?

Tags: azure, encryption

I have a program that pulls from azure key vault. When the data comes back it is in plain text. Is the data from the server to the client always in plain text and not encrypted?

Comment: Since all Azure requests are made using HTTPS with TLS1.2 or later, yes. All cloud vendors use HTTPS in their endpoints

Comment: The data in un-encrypted. It is the channel through which the data flows which is encrypted which is exactly what https is.